# Creating an array of arrays dynamically in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create the following array of arrays:

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 9],
 [1, 4, 16],
 [1, 5, 25],
 [1, 6, 36],
 [1, 7, 49],
 [1, 8, 64],
 [1, 9, 81],
 [1, 10, 100]]
```

And this is my code:

```
rows = 10
cols = 3
arr = []
x = [1, 1, 1]

for i in range(rows) :

    for j in range(cols) :
        x[j] = (i + 1) ** j

    arr.append(x)

print(arr)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[[1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100],
 [1, 10, 100]]
```

It seems like there's an error somewhere, but I cant see it, any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Add print statements for I, j, x[j] and i+1**j.  Do you see what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the same `x` array in every loop but create it from scratch:

```py
rows = 10
cols = 3
arr = []
for i in range(rows):
    x = []
    for j in range(cols):
        x.append((i + 1) ** j)
    arr.append(x)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you ?

```
rows = 10
arr = [[1, i, i*i] for i in range(1,rows + 1)]
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @Andrea's solution. You can think it in terms of powers:

`i**0` -> `0` ; `i**1` -> `1` ; `i**2` -> `i*i`, etc.

```
rows = 10
cols = 3
[[(i+1)**n for n in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
```